# why my if/else block doesn't work in redux toolkit reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

So basically I am making a shopping cart and I want to add a functionality if an item is already in the cart then increase it's quantity by 1. If you add same item and they have different sizes then show them separetely. I managed to deal with increasing the quantity in my reducer's logic but when I add another block condition it doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  bagData: [],
};

export const bagDataSlice = createSlice({
  name: "bagDataProducts",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    sendDataToCardComponent: (state, action) => {
      let { id, size } = action.payload;

      const findItemById = state.bagData.find(
        (item) => item.id === id && item.size === size
      );

      if (findItemById) {
        state.bagData.filter((item, i) => (state.bagData[i].quantity += 1));
      } else {
        state.bagData.push({ ...action.payload, quantity: 1 });
      }
    },
    increaseItemQuantity: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.bagData.filter((item, i) =>
        item.id === payload ? (state.bagData[i].quantity += 1) : item
      );
    },
    decreaseItemQuantity: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.bagData.filter((item, i) =>
        item.id === payload && item.quantity > 1
          ? (state.bagData[i].quantity -= 1)
          : item
      );
    },
    removeItem: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.bagData = state.bagData.filter((item) => item.id !== payload);
    },
  },
});
```

when I add the condition of

```
 const findItemById = state.bagData.find(
        (item) => item.id === id && item.size === size
      );
```

it only increments the item without checking it's size, only checks it's id even though there are 2 conditions for that function. Could you please explain that to me?

Comment: You are completely misusing `Array.prototype.filter()`

Comment: So what? It actually works and filters the items without erros. What would be the right solution then?

Comment: For the first 3, `find()`. Only the last one is correct. Basically, if you're setting properties within the `filter()` predicate, you're doing it wrong

Comment: what logic makes it wrong  indexing in filter method? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter according to the mdn documentation we can use indexing as a second paramater

Comment: In the first usage of `filter` you're using it to iterate through the entire array and increment each item's quantity. Not only you'd usually use `.forEach()` or a for loop for that, but I don't think that's what you intended.

Comment: @Asghwor when I click to the increment button it doesn't increment each item's quantity though. It only increments the ones I select.

Comment: `filter()` (and `map()` which is similarly abused) are used to return new arrays based on the callback function. If you just want to iterate, use `forEach()` or a `for` loop. If you want to find an element, use `find()`

Comment: @Phil okay. I changed them with forEach but it still doesn't work. It only adds items by comparing their id not their sizes. completely ignoring the second case

Comment: Weird. If `state.bagData` has all your items and you iterate over that array, it should be updating every item. Might have something to do with the way Redux Toolkit and Immer work.

Comment: @Asghwor it iterates the array and compares the id of the item that comes from the payload and then if they match it either adds to the bag or increases the quantity. It doesn't increase each item's quantity.

Comment: This `state.bagData.filter((item, i) => (state.bagData[i].quantity += 1))` is definitely iterating over every item in the array and updating them.

Comment: @Asghwor  item.id === payload ? (state.bagData[i].quantity += 1) : item there is a condition there. if id matches the id that comes from the payload then it increases if not it just returns the same item.

Comment: Not in `sendDataToCardComponent`, which is the one where the **first usage** I was mentioning.

Comment: @Asghwor there is another if condition there. if it finds the item then it increments. if (findItemById) {
        state.bagData.filter((item, i) => (state.bagData[i].quantity += 1));
      }

Comment: It increments everyone if the you find the one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```js
> state.bagData.filter((item, i) => (state.bagData[i].quantity += 1));
> ```

For your first case, this is updating **every** item's quantity if you found a matching item by `id` and `size`. Since you've already found the item and stored it in `findItemById`, you should be able to use the following.

*Caveat, Immer only supports [mutating array](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/update-patterns/#array-mutations) elements by index so use `findIndex()` instead of `find()`.*

```js
const itemIndex = state.bagData.findIndex(
  (item) => item.id === id && item.size === size
);

if (itemIndex !== -1) {
  state.bagData[itemIndex].quantity++;
} else {
  state.bagData.push({ ...action.payload, quantity: 1 });
}
```

Here's a quick demo showing that this works

```js
const initialState = {
  bagData: [{
    id: 1,
    quantity: 1,
    size: "S"
  }]
};

const sendDataToCardComponent = (action) =>
  immer.produce(initialState, (state) => {
    let { id, size } = action.payload;

    const itemIndex = state.bagData.findIndex(
      (item) => item.id === id && item.size === size
    );

    if (itemIndex !== -1) {
      state.bagData[itemIndex].quantity++;
    } else {
      state.bagData.push({ ...action.payload, quantity: 1 });
    }
  });

console.log(
  "increment existing",
  sendDataToCardComponent({ payload: { id: 1, size: "S" } })
);
console.log(
  "add new",
  sendDataToCardComponent({ payload: { id: 1, size: "M" } })
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/immer"></script>
```

---

As mentioned in the comments, you're misusing [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) which should only be used to return a new array with items filtered in or out based on a predicate. Your code can be cleaned up somewhat

```js
increaseItemQuantity: (state, { payload }) => {
  const found = state.bagData.findIndex(({ id }) => id === payload);
  if (found !== -1) {
    state.bagData[found].quantity++;
  }
},
decreaseItemQuantity: (state, { payload }) => {
  const found = state.bagData.findIndex(({ id }) => id === payload);
  if (found !== -1) {
    state.bagData[found].quantity--;
  }
},
```

Your last reducer is using `filter()` correctly but Immer also supports `splice()`

```js
removeItem: (state, { payload }) => {
  const found = state.bagData.findIndex(({ id }) => id === payload);
  if (found !== -1) {
    state.bagData.splice(found, 1);
  }
},
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! I implemented this code it looks indeed much better but still even though there are 2 parameters in the const itemIndex = state.bagData.findIndex(
  (item) => item.id === id && item.size === size
); it still doesn't add same items with different sizes to the bag instead increases its quantity by 1. Code looks better and much practical though but doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @berke-palamutcu Perhaps it's an error with the caller? Can you share that part of the code? A live demo would also help.

Comment: @BerkePalamutcu I've added a runnable demo that shows how it works. If you're seeing something different, I can only assume that either your state is not what you think it is or you're not sending the payload you think you are. Debugging with some simple `console.log()` lines should help you find the problem

Comment: @Phil I implemented the code you provided. It does exactly same thing with the previous code. It increments the items by 1 when I click the increment button or I am able to add different items to bag but, my main concern is to show same items with different size in the bag as different items. So I implemented const itemIndex = state.bagData.findIndex(
  (item) => item.id === id && item.size === size
); but that one doesn't check the size of the item that comes from the payload. it checks only if the ids are matched or not. when I try to add different size items, the quantity increases by 1.

Comment: @BerkePalamutcu and I've added a demo showing that is categorically not the case. What does your debugging tell you? A simple `console.log("bag", JSON.stringify(state.bagData)); console.log("payload", JSON.stringify(action.payload));` in `sendDataToCardComponent` will tell you everything you need to know

Comment: @Phil ohh seems like I made a typo error while trying to access item sizes. thank you. This literally solved the issue.

Comment: @BerkePalamutcu I can highly recommend using Typescript for your project. Typos basically become non-existent

Comment: @Phil I am a beginner and I am still at the learning phase.This is my first portfolio project after this one I will definitely stick with typescript. Thanks for the help again.

Comment: @BerkePalamutcu it's got something of a learning curve but is totally worth the time investment IMO